# Electron deBroglie wavelength and inertial frame

Tags: quantum-mechanics, special-relativity

Electron deBroglie wavelength is

$\lambda = \frac{h}{p}$

Now if I calculate the electron deBroglie wavelength for a low energy electron (KE = ~1 eV) it would be ~ 1 nm and as the energy increases this wavelength decreases.

My question is that if I change the frame of reference from lab frame (where electron has high energy) to the electron center of mass frame its deBroglie wavelength suddenly increases.

Can this change of inertial frame affect the interaction of electron with other particles.

Comment: You probably mean *de Broglie wavelength is* $\frac{h}{p}$, not $\frac{\lambda}{p}$.

Comment: @Thomas Fritsch Thanks. I have corrected the error

Answer (score 2):

You are talking about boost (changing to a moving the reference frame), quantum mechanics is not consistent with special relativity. Why? You can boost to a reference frame which is moving at 0.99999999 c. Then all the deBroglie wavelength of the particles become very very small and the cross section goes to zero. However, the cross section should be independent of the reference frame. In order to solve this problem you have to use quantum field theory to calculate cross sections and boost.